# What does CPU utilization mean?

Tags: performance, process, cpu-usage

When I say my utilization is 40% what does it mean actually?

This is my understanding: Say the CPU is capable of processing 100 instructions per second, whereas the CPU is given only 40 instructions (by all processes running) per second, then I can say it's 40% utilization.

Say out of 40 instructions, 30 instructions are given by process A and 10 instructions by process B. Then I can say process A's CPU utilization is 30% and 
process B's CPU utilization is 10%. Is that correct?

Comment: Why are you asking us what you mean?

Comment: He is asking whether his understanding about CPU utilization is correct, not what he means.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov There isn't one universal standard for what CPU utilization is or how it's measured. If someone says "my CPU utilization is 40%", unless it's clear from context, you have to ask them what they mean.

Comment: This question is legitimate in case of performance (performance tag). I think its not off-topic. It may look like an off-topic question because of way it is written. link given by Ms Yvette tries to answer similar question (very specific one actually) @scott miles, please comment or edit your question so that others can help you.